# Convert Object into XML element (and viceversa) in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

Is there any way to convert an object into an XML element in AS3?

I found this tutorial to serialize them:

http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Serializing_object_to_XML-11988.html

But I also need a way to unserialize to get the original object (with its own properties) and ready to `stage.addChild`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*disclaimer: In the following message, when I write (un)serialize I talk about XML*

You can (un)serialize a data object with properties such as numbers, arrays, objects or strings. But you can't (un)serialize a graphic object if you don't have all the instructions needed to rebuild it.

The last part of your question (adding to stage the unserialized object) made me think you want to (un)serialize a `DisplayObject`. If the construction of your `DisplayObject` can be summarize with some properties (the URL of an image in a `Loader`, or the size and color of a rectangle in a `Shape`) you can develop an *ad hoc* serializer. But this won't work for any custom `Sprite`.

Comment: If you use the new(ish) drawGraphicsData() and drawPath() methods to draw the display object graphics, then you can store the drawing commands in an instance variable (and serialize/deserialize them).